# Why isn't "SHOW TABLES" working

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I'm using drupal. **This code works on the test database, but when I move the code to the live site, it isn't showing anything.**I can use the "SHOW TABLES" command on the live database through the command prompt, but not through drupal. What could be going on?

```
$result = db_query("SHOW TABLES"); // get all the tables
  while ($obj = db_fetch_object($result))
  {
    $content .= "<br /><strong>" . $obj->Tables_in_test . "</strong>";
    $result_desc = db_query("DESC $obj->Tables_in_test"); //get the columns in each table
    while ($obj_desc = db_fetch_object($result_desc)) 
    {
      $content .=  "<br />". $obj_desc->Field . " " . ("PRI" == $obj_desc->Key ? "(PK)" : $obj_desc->Key);
    }
    $content .=  "<br />";
  }
  return $content;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Unexpected result? Have you tried running the command via a CLI session? What happenned?

Comment: What is your drupal version?

Comment: I don't get an error. Notice this script works for the test database, but not the live database. I'm running Drupal 6.

Comment: Does the database user have appropriate permissions on the tables?  (I seem to remember stuff being invisible in MySQL in some cases when i tried to `SHOW` stuff i didn't have access to...)

Comment: @AllisonC Your code works for me, make sure the DB user you're connecting with has sufficient `SELECT` privileges

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I got it to work. I had to change "Tables_in_test" to "Tables_in_main"